# How do you connect two firebase projects in one flutter app?

Tags: python, firebase, flutter, api, backend

I'm currently working on this software where there are two apps, one for the client and another for the partners. The client app has to communicate with the backend of the partner app but the backend of the partner app is in another firebase project. How do I connect the firebase backend of client app to that of the partner app in flutter (both apps are in flutter).
Is there some way that I could do it using a separate api?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [secondary apps](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage#secondary-firebase-apps)

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'SecondaryApp',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        appId: 'my_appId',
        apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
        messagingSenderId: 'my_messagingSenderId',
        projectId: 'my_projectId'
    )
);
```

Accessing secondary apps

Once initialized, secondary apps can be accessed via the app method on FirebaseCore:

```
FirebaseApp secondaryApp = Firebase.app('SecondaryApp');
```

Comment: @shimron you can mark as answer as it helped you